# New column based on multiple conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am struggling a little bit on Power BI - I want to be able to differentiate between two products based on the type of product and a create a new column with a new name based on the criteria, see example below.

EG

| Product | Size | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mattress | King | Bespoke |
| Mattress | Queen | Bespoke |
| Mattress | Single | Regular |
| Mattress | Double | Regular |

I want to be able to add the type on Power BI without having to do it manually so it automatically determines if the size of the mattress is King then it will add Bespoke in the column for type.

So far I am having to do it manually as this is how we get the raw data - it was fairly easy to do on Excel but since the migration to Power BI I have been struggling with the volumes to do manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this **calculated column**:

```
Type Formula = 
SWITCH(
    'Table'[Size],
    "King", "Bespoke",
    "Queen", "Bespoke",
    "Single", "Regular",
    "Double", "Rgular"
)
```

[image]